# react.js wrong resuilt when converting timestamp to date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a UNIX timestamp to date in react.js. It works well but the only thing is that I get the wrong year. I just can't understand why it happens. I think it is probably the problem with my computer or other things but I just can't figure it out.

Here is my log in to the browser.

```
Object { seconds: 1620198000, nanoseconds: 0 }  // The timestamp value
Date Sat May 05 3990 00:00:00 GMT-0700         // The converted date
```

And also my code here

```
const date= new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000)
return (
    <p>{date.toTimeString()}</p>   // Getting 3990/5/5 instead of 2021/5/5
)
```

Comment: what's the value of `unixTimestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp is `firebase.firestore.Timestamp`, isn't it?
You can

```js
timestamp.toDate()
```

to get Date object.

By the way, how did you get `unixTImestamp`? `new Date(1620198000 * 1000)` returns correct timestamp,
`Wed May 05 2021 16:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)`

I assume you `new Date(timestamp.seconds * 1000)` will give you the expected result.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate

Comment: It worked! Adding .seconds does solve the problem. I have been suffered from this for a whole night and you just saved my day man.